# Why is the function output always 5?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

does anyone know why the output of this code is 5 times 5?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000 );   
}
```

The for statement never gets to 5 :S

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a closure in order to preserve the value of the `i` variable. Otherwise, the `i` variable will be the value of the last iteration when the `setTimeout` executes

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000 );
    })(i);   
}
```

Take a look into reading about [**IIFEs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: Don't need to create a closure for this. You can accept an argument on the setTimeout function and pass it as a parameter after the delay

Answer (score 1):

Just modify a little your code, and it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(x) { console.log(x); }, i * 1000, i);   
}
```

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: heh, nice, didnt know that. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic example of closure:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In
>   other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the
>   environment in which it was created.

Your inner function has access to the environment (in this example with the outer variable *i*). After the loop has ended the value of *i* is 5 and your function use this value. of course if you use *console.log(i)* after the loop will end.

Try this article - [Closure - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)